# PHP variable value not being displayed in JS alert

Tags: javascript, php, forms, submit

In the following code, I've generated a php form that takes in values from a user for an arp network attack I'm working on. However, I'm trying to display the number of packets sent "$loops" in the javascript alert, when I run the code the number of packets is not displayed in the alert, and I don't know what went wrong so if someone could go through and flow of my code I'd appreciate it very much.

```
<form method ='post' action ="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">

<?php $loops = "";?>

<b> <p>Number of packets to be sent:</p>
<input type="text" name="loops" value="<?php echo $loops;?>">
<br><br></b>

<?php
$php_var = $loops;?>


<p style="text-align: center;">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button></p><br>  
<script>
    function myFunction() {
            var js_var = "The number of packets sent is: <?php echo $php_var; ?>";
                    alert(js_var);
                        }
</script>
</font>
</form>


<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]== "POST"){
if(isset($_POST["loops"])){
    $loops=$_REQUEST['loops'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning `$php_var` to blank here.

```
<?php $loops = "";?>

<?php $php_var = $loops;?>
```

So, its displaying no value.

I think you need to take value input by user in textbox.

```
<input type="text" name="loops" value="<?php echo $loops;?>" id="loops"> // Observe the added `id` attribute.
```

You can do it like:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  //var js_var = "The number of packets sent is: <?php echo $php_var; ?>";
  var val = document.getElementById('loops').value;
  var js_var = "The number of packets sent is: " + val;
  alert(js_var);
}
</script>
```

Comment: isn't  it taking the value inserted user value from   <input type="text" name="loops" value="<?php echo $loops;?>">

Answer (score 0):

try like

```
<?php $loops = "123";?>
    function myFunction() {
      var js_var = "The number of packets sent is: <?php echo $php_var; ?> ";
      alert(js_var);
    }
```

Comment: This is not displaying the alert in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 <form method ='post' action ="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">

          $loops = isset($_POST["loops"])?$_POST["loops"]:"";

         <b> <p>Number of packets to be sent:</p>
        <input type="text" name="loops" value="<?php echo $loops;?>">
        <br><br></b>

       <?php
       $php_var = $loops;?>


       <p style="text-align: center;">
         <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button></p><br>  
        <script>
function myFunction() {
        var js_var = "The number of packets sent is: <?php echo $php_var; ?>";
                alert(js_var);
                    }
        </script>
     </font>
       </form>


      <?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]== "POST"){
      if(isset($_POST["loops"])){
         $loops=$_REQUEST['loops'];
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use PHP at the starting of the page always. Its required so that you can get the variables available in HTML.

```
    <form method ='post' action ="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

    <?php $loops = ''; ?>
    <?php if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            if (isset($_POST["loops"])) {
                $loops = $_REQUEST['loops'];
            }
        }
        ?>
        <b>
            <p>Number of packets to be sent:</p>
            <input type="text" name="loops" value="<?php echo $loops; ?>">
            <br><br>
        </b>
        <?php $php_var = $loops; ?>
        <p style="text-align: center;">
            <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
        </p>
        <br>  
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var js_var = "The number of packets sent is: <?php echo $php_var; ?>";
                alert(js_var);
            }
        </script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check if there is any `$_REQUEST['loops']` after `$loop` variable initialization.

so the code should be

```
<?php
    $loops = "";

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]== "POST"){
        if(isset($_POST["loops"])){
            $loops=$_REQUEST['loops'];
        }
    }
?>

<form method ='post' action ="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">

<b> <p>Number of packets to be sent:</p>
<input type="text" name="loops" value="<?php echo $loops;?>">
<br><br></b>

<?php
$php_var = $loops;?>


<p style="text-align: center;">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button></p><br>  
<script>
    function myFunction() {
            var js_var = "The number of packets sent is: <?php echo $php_var; ?>";
                    alert(js_var);
                        }
</script>
</font>
</form>
```